# How to find previously installed location

Tags: wix

I am using Wix Burn to upgrade our program with some prerequisites. The program needs to be installed in the same location that previously installed. How can I find the installed location? I am thinking about to find it from the registry Uninstall folder, however, sometimes it is not even there. Even if it is there, how do I get it from Burn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367579(v=vs.85).aspx) to locate components installed by the previous installation. You can then set the installation directory dynamically by using the results of that [ComponentSearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentsearch.html). All of this is done in the msi itself, burn is not involved in that process. The only thing you have to do with the burn bundle is to change the version number and to make sure that the UpgradeCode of the previous bundle matches the UpgradeCode of the current bundle. Bear in mind that, unlike in msi packages, the last part of the version number of a burn bundle is significant. You will also need to change the version number of the msi.

To make this work, it is necessary the previous bundle installed a component of which the GUID is known to you, and that component needs to reside inside the folder you want to upgrade.

```
<!-- ComponentSearch -->
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="PREVIOUS_INSTALL_FOLDER">
        <ComponentSearch Id="MyComponentSearch" Guid="KNOWN_GUID_OF_PREVIOUSLY_INSTALLED_COMPONENT" />
    </Property>
</Fragment>

<!-- Increment Product Version, Reference Component Search, Set Target Location -->
<Product 
    ...
    Version="INCREMENTED_VERSION_NUMBER"
    UpgradeCode="HAS_TO_MATCH_PREVIOUSLY_INSTALLED_UC">
        <SetProperty 
        Id="DYNAMIC_PROGRAM_LOCATION" 
        Value="[PREVIOUS_INSTALL_FOLDER]" 
        After="AppSearch" Sequence="ui" Action="SetDynamicProgramLocation">
            <![CDATA[PREVIOUS_INSTALL_FOLDER]]>
        </SetProperty>
</Product>

<!-- Folder Layout -->
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="DYNAMIC_PROGRAM_LOCATION" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```